# How to get post ID with hooks publish_post, new_to_publish, etc

Tags: plugins, hooks, actions, id

I have two plugins, one uses the function wp_insert_post(), the other has a code like this:

```
add_action('future_to_publish', 'myFunc', 10, 1);
add_action('new_to_publish', 'myFunc', 10, 1);
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'myFunc', 10, 1);

function myFunc( $postID ) {

}
```

When the first plugin runs wp_insert_post(), $postID is always empty. If I use the hook "publish_post" and press update then $postID does have a value, so what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

1. Read the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/%20Post_Status_Transitions),
2. Look at the [function in the core file](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/post.php#L3226),
3. Modify your code as follows:

   ```
   function myFunc( $post ) {

       $postID = $post->ID;

   }
   ```

The post transistion does not send the post ID, it sends the complete post object. Sometimes a simple `die(var_dump($postID));` (or whatever you use as parameter) helps to find out what will be send to the callback. If you don't know how many parameters are send to the callback, put a `die(var_dump(func_get_args()));` at the first line of your callback.

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunc( $post ) {
    global $post;
    $myPostId = $post->ID;

    //your function here

}
```

For getting the $postID value, you just insert `global $post` expression in your function. 
It worked for me.

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question.

Comment: "This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content", which I am sure you don't want. Please explain what your code does and why it would solve the problem.

Comment: It is answering the question.
JUST READ THE ENTIRE ORIGINAL QUESTION:
"$postID is always empty".
For getting the $postID value, you just insert global $post expression in your function.
@s_ha_dum, I appreciate your answer but you become too zealous (not jealous) in your willing to help

Comment: See the answer by @Ralf912

Comment: answer by @Ralf912 it is not complete! you MUST call the global `global $post;` if it's a plugin file - which it is. Again, READ the freaking question, this is not poker to read the players.

Comment: [The post object is passed through those filters to the callback](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/post.php#L3238). You don't need `global` anything because that function, by way of being hooked to those filters, already has access to the `$post` data. It doesn't matter if this a plugin or not. `$postID`, in the original code, should (probably) never be empty but trying to use an Object like a string or an integer might make it appear that way. That is ___not___ my downvote, by the way, and I'd appreciate it if you'd try not to be rude.

Answer (score 0):

[`wp_insert_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) returns the post ID on success. The value 0 or [WP_Error](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_error/) on failure.

```
$postId = wp_insert_post($args);
if(!$postId){
echo "Your post is not inserted that's why you've no post id :p"
}
```